# Issue with writing JSONB data into postgresql using fastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am running into an issue when tring to write or update a JSONB column in postgreSQL. The programm is using sqlalchemy for all database operations and ORM, pydantic for data validation and fastAPI.

sqlalchemy model:

```
class Entry_A(Base):
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid4)
    state_transition_data: Mapped[JSONB] = mapped_column(JSONB, nullable=True)
```

pydantic model:

```
class Entry_A(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    state_transition_data: JSON | None
```

JSON object

```
    state_transition_data = {
        "itemId": int,
        "transitions": [
            {
                "isValueAdd": boolean,
                "fromState": str,
                "toState": str,
                "entered": datetime,
                "exited": datetime,
                "totalTimeSpendInState": timedelta,
            }
        ],
    }
```

crud operation:

```
    def update(self, db: Session, *, db_obj: Entry_A, obj_in: Entry_A) -> Entry_A:
        if isinstance(obj_in, dict):
            update_data = obj_in
        else:
            update_data = obj_in.dict(exclude_unset=True)
        return super().update(db, db_obj=db_obj, obj_in=update_data)
```

super().update()

```
    def update(self, db: Session, *, db_obj: ModelType, obj_in: Union[UpdateSchemaType, Dict[str, Any]]) -> ModelType:
        obj_data = jsonable_encoder(db_obj)
        if isinstance(obj_in, dict):
            update_data = obj_in
        else:
            update_data = obj_in.dict(exclude_unset=True)
        for field in obj_data:
            if field in update_data:
                setattr(db_obj, field, update_data[field])
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

endpoint:

```
@router.post("/", response_model=None):
def update_entry( 
    *,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    obj_in: schemas.Entry_A,
) -> Any:
    previous_entry = get_entry(
        db=db, id=obj_in.id
    )
    previous_state_transitions = previous_entry.state_transition_data
    new_transition = {
            "isValueAdd": new_value,
            "fromState": new value,
            "toState": new_value,
            "entered": new_value,
            "exited": None,
            "total_time_spend_in_state": None,
        }
        previous_state_transitions["transitions"].append(new_transition)
        previous_state_transitions_json = json.dumps(previous_state_transitions)

        event_in = schemas.Entry_A(
        state_transition_data=previous_state_transitions_json
    )
    event = crud.update(db=db, db_obj=previous_entry, obj_in=event_in)
    return event
```

Doing this depending on if the type annotation I get 2 different results:

1. pydantic type annotation `Json`, the column does not get updated. I think the issue is that the object being given to the database contains single quote instead double quotes. When trying to insert this directly the DB complains.

e.g.

```
{'itemId': 264, 'transitions': [{'exited': '2023-11-30T09:21:38.747723+00:00', 'entered': '2023-11-28T11:19:53.622035+00:00', 'toState': 'NEW ORDER', 'fromState': None, 'isValueAdd': False, 'totalTimeSpendInState': '22:01:45'}, {'isValueAdd': True, 'fromState': 'NEW ORDER', 'toState': 'MATERIAL PREPARATION', 'entered': '2023-11-30T09:21:38.748487+00:00', 'exited': None, 'totalTimeSpendInState': None}]}
```

2. If the pydantic type annotation is changed von `Json` to `Any` it writes an update to the column, but escapes everything and I can't perform any queries on the data afterwards.

e.g.

```
"{\"itemId\": 264, \"transitions\": [{\"exited\": \"2023-11-30T09:42:17.109888+00:00\", \"entered\": \"2023-11-28T11:19:53.622035+00:00\", \"toState\": \"NEW ORDER\", \"fromState\": null, \"isValueAdd\": false, \"totalTimeSpendInState\": \"22:22:23\"}, {\"isValueAdd\": true, \"fromState\": \"NEW ORDER\", \"toState\": \"MATERIAL PREPARATION\", \"entered\": \"2023-11-30T09:42:17.110583+00:00\", \"exited\": null, \"totalTimeSpendInState\": null}]}"
```

Comment: I made a mistake while describing the issues, the text has been updated to correct that.

Comment: You should not need to use `json.dumps` with a SQLAlchemy JSON field. What happens if you remove that, and just use `previous_state_transitions`?

Comment: If I remove `json.dumps` and keep the pydantic model with `state_transition_data: Json` the following error shows up: `state_transition_data
  JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray (type=type_error.json)`. When annotating with `Any` the field won't be updated.

Comment: I think the problem is inside your `crud.update`. I tried to do the same with clear SQLAlchemy and it works well

Comment: The `super.update` looks like this currently:
`
    def update(self, db: Session, *, db_obj: ModelType, obj_in: Union[UpdateSchemaType, Dict[str, Any]]) -> ModelType:
        obj_data = jsonable_encoder(db_obj)
        if isinstance(obj_in, dict):
            update_data = obj_in
        else:
            update_data = obj_in.dict(exclude_unset=True)
        for field in obj_data:
            if field in update_data:
                setattr(db_obj, field, update_data[field])
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj